# Windows Phone - Extract image section from Map Control

Tags: maps, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bing-maps

I'm using the Windows Phone 8 Map Control. I want to extract a part of the displayed map as image to use it as a tile. 
Is there a built-in functionality because the native maps app is doing the same if you pin a location as tile.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to display the map in the tile would be to use the static imagery REST service from Bing Maps if it's what you're seeking, see the MSDN for further information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

You'll be able to generate the static image that you can use in your tiles and there are options so you can set center, style and even add content to it.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but the returned image contains the Bing logo and this would break my style.

Comment: You can generate it larger than required and cut it afterwards. But I don't think any mapping platform would allow to use their imagery (road or satellite style) without displaying the logo. Nokia's Here Map Image API could do this but with really special agreement and a hidden parameter

Comment: Thats right. I've found another good solution. I capture the whole screen (with the map) and cut it to a rectangle which fits in my tile. Is it possible to calculate the absolute coordinates from the relative map coordinates, that I know where the center is?